# Append data to csv file

Tags: r, list, csv, append

I use the "tuber" library for R. In this code snippet I load a file with IDs YouTube-channels and write the information to a vector. Next step in the loop I go through the ID and paste an array element (youtube channel) as an argument to the "list_channel_videos" function. The result of the function is a list with information about the channel. How can I write information about all channels sequentially to a csv file? If I use this code, information recorded only about the last channel from the array.

```
vtest <- read.csv2("tester.csv", header = FALSE)
arrv <- as.matrix(vtest)
arv <- as.vector(arrv)
iterator <- 1
for (iterator in 1:length(arv)) {
 nv <- list_channel_videos(channel_id = arv[iterator])
 write.csv2(nv, file="bb.csv", append = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` and combine the output in one dataframe.

```
nv <- do.call(rbind, lapply(arv, list_channel_videos))
#You can also use `purrr`'s `map_df` function
nv <- purrr::map_df(arv, list_channel_videos)
```

Write this data together in a csv file.

```
write.csv2(nv, file="bb.csv")
```

Comment: I have a new question: how i can count iterations in lapply?

Comment: @AlexeyDidorenko Can you ask that as a new question?

Comment: Just here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307410/how-can-i-count-iterations-in-lapply?)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
nv <- rbindlist(lapply(arv, list_channel_videos))

fwrite(nv, 'bb.csv')
```

Comment: Ok, Thank You too. I have a new question: how i can count iterations in lapply?