# How can i count iterations in lapply?

Tags: r, count, iteration, lapply

How to count iterations in lapply? R

```
IDsVidYT <- do.call(rbind, lapply(arv, list_channel_videos))
```

Comment: `length(arv)` is the number of iterations.

Comment: Ok, but during working lapply i get a errors and lapply stop. I need to know number of iteration, which stop the process

Comment: I'd switch to a for loop in that case.

Comment: For "list_channel_videos" function it do not work correctly

Comment: `results <- list(); for(i in seq_along(arv)) {results[[i]] <- list_channel_videos(arv[[i]])}` should be equivalent to the `lapply`. When it errors, you can see what value `i` is. Or you could stick something like `message("Trying arv number ", i)` in your loop.

Comment: Did you try Gregor's suggestion using `for` loop ? That should work.

Comment: @GregorThomas I just tried this method now. It works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @RonakShah I just tried this method now. It works! Thank you very much!